# My app closes without any warning or error message

Tags: iphone, opengl, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm programming an puzzle game for iPhone using openGL.

There Is one very weird "bug" ( I'm not sure what It is)... whenever I touch the screen a great number of times in a short period of time my app closes, without giving a warning or error.

What could be the cause ?, I guess It has something to do with the memory, but I would like to know.

Edit:
I also think this happens because I'm calling multiple functions every time the user touches the screen or moves his fingers.

Comment: Are you talking about the simulator or the iPhone?

Comment: This happens only in the iPhone, this never happens with the simulator.

Comment: are your low memory methods on delegate being called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're running out of memory.

A few quick tips that might help out:

- Check your memory profile over time using Instruments.  If you see a steady incline over time, it's likely to be a memory leak, or an inefficient algorithm that is allocating more memory than you need.
- Use a static analyzer to help check for leaks, such as [Clang](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).
- Images and image-related files are particularly memory-hungry, so focus on efficiency for them.  When you work with textures in OpenGL, use the PVRTC format, which offers awesome compression.
- [`didReceiveMemoryWarning:` is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582401/iphone-helpfulness-of-didreceivememorywarning) - aka a good chance to throw out anything you don't absolutely need in memory.  Better to be memory-efficient the whole time, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an [NSUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/iphone-exception-handling). You may also want to setup a [signal handler](http://www.restoroot.com/Blog/2008/10/20/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications-part-2/).