# iOS 4.0.1 "fast app switching" behavior in simulator vs device (iPhone 4)

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

I'm testing an iPhone app in both the simulator (XCode 3.2.3, iPhone SDK 4.0.1) and on the device (iPhone 4 and iOS 4.0.1).  The simulator exhibits the expected "fast app switching" behavior while the device does not.

**Simulator**:

- click home button while app is running => go back to home screen
- click the app icon => app resumes where it left-off (app does not restart)

**Device**

- click home button while app is running => go back to home screen
- click the app icon => app restarts (does not resume from the user quit)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your phone is low on memory.

Comment: looks like this might be the case.  my app does load a non-trivial amount of resources into memory (and doesn't release them when the app "moves into the background").  anyways I tested moving the stop-watch (Apple's clock app) into the background and bringing it back and the app did not restart (in fact it kept running in the background).

Comment: If this is the case... MrDatabase, could you tell us what is the output of your console? Is there anything like Memory Warning level 3?

Comment: You may also want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582401/iphone-helpfulness-of-didreceivememorywarning/582648#582648

Comment: Turns out it was because I was making OpenGL calls after the app entered the background.  Memory was not the issue.