# What does ios when it calls didreceivememorywarning?

Tags: iphone

I want to know What does ios when it calls didreceivememorywarning?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice discussion about DidReceiveMemoryWarning in this question: [iOS: helpfulness of didReceiveMemoryWarning:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582401/iphone-helpfulness-of-didreceivememorywarning)