# Can you explain me briefly how didReceiveMemoryWarning works?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: helpfulness of didReceiveMemoryWarning:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582401/iphone-helpfulness-of-didreceivememorywarning)
>   [How to implement didReceiveMemoryWarning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430728/how-to-implement-didreceivememorywarning)

I want to know how this function works.  It calls the parent class's `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. But I don't know that what is written in this function and how it works.

Comment: You can see [HERE](http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2009/08/handling-didreceivememorywarning/), and [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430728/how-to-implement-didreceivememorywarning) is a question on "How to implement didReceiveMemoryWarning?". :)

Answer (score 1):

**`didReceiveMemoryWarning`** is called when the class starts using too much memory. You can use this method to release objects that are not being used such as images, arrays, dictionaries, etc.

Comment: How can i see the code written in the body of didReceiveMemoryWarning ?

Comment: You write the code. Standard code in `didReceiveMemoryWarning ` is **`[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];`**

Comment: I know that this is calling the parent class didReceiveMemoryWarning function. but what is written in the parent class didReceiveMemoryWarning function?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Read the documentation on it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Don't mind but tell me that without any body how can                             [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; this function works? I have only 4 month experience in iPhone and i want to clear my all problems in iPhone. thats why i have posted this question.

Comment: I already explained to you that you need to release unused objects. See the above answer, theres not much more to it.